# Using redis as intermediary before MySQL insert

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, redis

We're writing a chat application, partially in node.js. We're expecting 1000s of inserts (messages) per second, and so our approach has been to write to redis (using an lrange for each room), and also have a list in redis called not_saved_messages that another process loops through and writes to MySQL.  Is this an anti pattern? Should we just be writing to MySQL and hope it holds up?

Comment: Doesn't seem like an anti-pattern and a practical way to deal with bursts of inserts. You're basically using Redis as a message queue. I would probably want to keep an eye on the latency, since depending on what parts of your app are drawing from the MySQL store, the latency might impact the user's experience or expectations. Seems a reasonable approach overall though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of inserting the data directly, you can first store it in
>   Redis. Then second process can pick it up from Redis and insert it
>   into the database, one "data portion" at a time. Drawback here is you
>   will need to have enought memory for Redis.

```
// PHP program code
//...
// assuming $r is already connected Redis() instance.
$r->sadd("data_pipe", serialize($data));
```

Then,

```
// Open connection to the database
open_data_connection();

$r = new Redis();
$r->connect("127.0.0.1", "6379");

while(true){
    while($xdata = $r->spop("data_pipe")){
        $data = unserialize($xdata);

        // store the data
        store_data($data);
    }

    // No more data
    sleep(30);
}
```

> If database can not keep up, e.g. insert data as fast as new data come
>   in, you can always start the pick up process twice or more, or to do
>   some kind of sharding, by importing the data in 2-3 databases.

http://redis4you.com/code.php?id=016

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is necessarily an antipattern if it is well done.  The devil of course is in the details.

What you are trying to do is use mysql for logging and redis for live information, right?  It seems to me that might work.  The question is how to make the pipeline as a whole function.

BTW, a number of big data users use something very close to this result.  CERN for example uses a number of NoSQL solutions during their data processing before the data goes into an rdbms (Oracle, PostgreSQL, or MySQL).  But it is definitely advanced design territory.

Comment: I guess you can say it's more than just logging, as some of the more advanced features of the application will be handled in MySQL. It's quite possible that Redis can handle it all but there's discomfort in relying on Redis for all data storage. Also, the part covered by Redis is a small subset of a larger application.  I hope that makes sense.